# Догружать страницу, пропуская ошибки

Tags: php

Есть странице. На странице есть php запрос к другому серверу. 
Как грузить страницу до конца, если подключения к серверу нет?
Сейчас у меня просто подгружается страница до того места где происходит ошибка. 
Обернул в try-catch - не помогло.

Comment: Как подгружаете стороннюю страницу?

Comment: Да там не страница подгружается, а выполняется json-rpc запрос на другой сервер.